# 403 Forbidden Access to this resource on the server is denied

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Estoy subiendo una pagina web desarrollada con Laravel a mi hosting en este caso 'Hostinger' ya subí todos mis archivos a la carpeta **public_html** pero me aparece el error **403 Forbidden**. Configure mi archivo **.env** para que funcionara como dice la documentación genere la **key** conecte la base de datos y nada. Vi en muchos lados que la causa del problema es muchas veces los permisos de las carpetas y archivos por eso desde FileZilla configure todas las carpetas con **775** y los archivos con **644** y tampoco se resolvió el problema. Probé configurando las **.htaccess** y tampoco me resolvió el problema. Me gustaría saber si estoy haciendo algo mal con respecto al problema o si me olvide de algún paso a la hora de tanto configurar el hosting o de pasar a producción el proyecto. Les dejo algunos archivos que creo yo son el punto clave para resolver el problema para ver si me pueden ayudar. Desde ya gracias.
Posibles soluciones que intente:
Estoy hace 3 días tratando de resolver esto y problema realmente con creería yo todo desde modificar el archivo **.htaccess**, de modificar las rutas, los controladores, cambiar de lugar el archivo **public_html/public/index.php** a **public_html/index.php** funciono sin nada adentro pero cuando le ponía el código adentro con las rutas modificadas corrompía todo y dejaba de funcionar hasta el dominio, configure las DNS que estuviera bien configurada desde Clouflare a Hostinger, borre el cache desde el **SSH** no funciono. Ya no se que me falta hacer para ver si funciona.
**Archivo .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
 RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]


 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
 #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [L]
```

**Archivo index.php que se ubica en el siguiente path public_html/public/index.php**

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));



if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}



require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';



$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
)->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**Archivo .env modificado para no comprometer datos**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=produccion
APP_KEY=(Esta generada)
BCRYPT_ROUNDS=10
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=(conectado)
DB_USERNAME=(conectado)
DB_PASSWORD=(conectado)

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Puede llegar a ser la configuración de mis rutas o en si mi proyecto es la primera vez que trabajo con laravel y el único problema que tuve es este a la hora de subirlo. Mil gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Probaste en encender el debug en el .env para que te muestre el error?

Comment: Recordá siempre que [es.so] no es un foro, por lo tanto, no escribas "solucionado" en el título. El equivalente de "solucionado" en este sitio es cuando aceptás tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de mas de una semana investigando y leyendo documentación (Que en ningún lado te explica por que se genera este error) encontré la solución.
Lo que hice fue crear un archivo .htaccess en mi carpeta raíz de hosting que es este caso es public_html:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Este código hace que se redirija a la carpeta public que dentro de ella esta el archivo index.php y dentro de la carpeta /public genere un archivo .htaccess con el siguente codigo para que me lea el index.php y funciono correctamente

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    
    # Redireccionar sin /public en la URL
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTPS_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTPS:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Teniendo el cuenta que todas las carpetas están con permisos en 755 y los archivos en 644 les tendría que andar perfectamente! Esto es para **laravel 10.8** usando **php con versión 8.1**
Espero que a alguien le funcione como me funciono a mi.